# How to use setters and getters for array

Tags: java

okay so on my class diagram it shows

```
void setVegetable( String veg[] )
String veg[] getVegetables()
```

Just wondering how I would code the statement for this?

```
public void setVegetables( String veg[] )  
{  
}
```

also how would I write the instance variables?
do I still write it as

```
private string vegetables = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to use a member definition like this:

```
private String[] vegetables;
```

And a setter like this:

```
public void setVegetables( String veg[] ) {  
    vegetables = veg;
}
```

However you should keep in mind that a array is modifiable meaning that if you store the array directly like in the setter described above the caller will still be able to modify the content of the array so it's a good practice to copy the array content if you want a better encapsulation. Though this will have impact on performances if you manipulate large arrays.
In this case the setter and getter will look like this

```
public void setVegetables( String veg[] ) {  
    vegetables = Arrays.copyOf(veg, veg.length);
}

public String[] getVegetables() {  
    return Arrays.copyOf(vegetables, vegetables.length);
}
```

Comment: `this.vegetables = vegetables.clone();` s clearer. Although really you'd want to use `List<>` and probably something more specific than `String`.

Comment: also note that this creates a copy of the array pointing to the same objects (which is of no importance here since Stings are immutable). That lets the caller modify objects in the first array.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like

```
private String[] vegetables;
```

and the setter method

```
public void setVegetables( String[] veg )  { this.vegetables = veg; )
```

or suffer a compile error - An array of `String`'s is *not* the same as a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the variable:

```
private String vegetables;
```

to an array:

```
private String vegetables[];
```

then normally set and get the instance array using the setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :

`public void setVegetables( String[] veg )  {  }`

Comment: add it would do nothing ? that's an original version of a setter

Comment: yes, it won't do anything yet. I'm just addressing your syntactical error on `setVegetables` param

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values to the local variable when you initialise it like this:

```
private String[] vegetables = new String[]{"Carrot", "Parsnip"};
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your class diagram, the instance variable you are looking at is a String array. So the instance member has to be a String[] as well. 
The declaration should be like

```
private String[] vegetables;
public void setVegetables( String vegetables[] ) {  
    this.vegetables = vegetables;
}

public String[] getVegetables() {  
    return vegetables;
}
```